# Doing a regex Mongo search in a node.js app with a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

Basic functionality of my app: customers begin to type an email address into a input field and receive auto-suggested results that match the characters they've input.

I've tried implementing this in Mongoose/Mongo in my node app like so:

```
let customer = await Customer.find({
   'email_address': {
     $regex: searchQuery
   }
 })
```

Important to note that I actually have an index set up for `email_address`, in order to improve performance, but I read somewhere that using `regex` will void searching through an index? I read the docs on this but I'm just more confused. In any case, the main crux of the question is below:

I know that by doing something like `/^exampleEmailAddress/`, it will match results that start with the query (not a wildcard search). This is what I want.

But, how do I do this when the `exampleEmailAddress` is a variable I've obtained from `req.query`? I've tried:

```
let customer = await Customer.find({
  'email_address': {
    $regex: /^`${searchQuery}`/
  }
})
```

which isn't working. I feel like I'm missing something basic here...

Comment: any regex or like query will never use the index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the class [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```
const customer = await Customer.find({
  email_address: {
    $regex: new RegExp(`^${searchQuery}`),
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Regex` expression for that particular property on your documents. And you can search for case insensitivity using `i` as mentioned

```
customer.find({ "email_address": new RegExp(searchQuery, 'i') }, function (err, task) {
if (err)
  res.send(err);
 res.json(task);
 });
```

Note. `req` and `res` may be your request and response objects